# Content Types reverting to default

Tags: 2013, content-type

I have a peculiar problem and am looking for pointers as to what I might check.  I have a number of users that when they edit a document that is already set to one content type, on saving it the document reverts back to the default content type.  However, it doesn't do it for all the users, or for me.

User Access is defined by Active Directory groups and I am essential only at poweruser level access so I can't get into the global settings.

Has anybody else come across this and, if so, how did you solve it?

Thanks, Steve

Comment: is there no possible way that they are inadvertently switching the content type on the document? The only time I've run into an issue similar to this is when users where creating items view the quick edit grid view with multiple content types on the list. Every time it created an item it would choose the default content type (which makes sense since they can't choose what content type in the quick edit view).

Comment: We are not using quick edit, but thanks indeed for having a look for me. It might be that a pattern is starting to develop, but with it being intermittent I can't yet be sure.  It seems (don't ask me how!) that the problem is around encrypted Microsoft Word and Excel documents.  I'm surprised that this should make a difference, and it might be red herring, but I'll continue to monitor and report back to this thread if it looks more so.  Thanks again, Steve.